# Location search query issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables Location, Country and CountryAlias. I want to find the locations country. Means **I want to search location_name from location table against Country and CountryAlias and find the country code**.
But while do like query. I am getting wrong output.

**location**

```
location_name

Bangalore, India
India
Chennai, India
```

**Country**

```
code   name
IN     India
IO     British Indian Ocean Territory
```

**CountryAlias**

```
code   alias
IN     Bharth
IN     Hindustan
```

Try Query

```
SELECT code from Country 
LEFT JOIN CountryAlias ON Country.code = CountryAlias.code 
where Country.`name` LIKE '%Bangalore, India%' or CountryAlias.alias LIKE '%Bangalore, India%'
```

O/P  = NuLL

```
 SELECT code from Country 
    LEFT JOIN CountryAlias ON Country.code = CountryAlias.code 
    where Country.`name` LIKE '%India%' or CountryAlias.alias LIKE '%India%'
```

O/P  = IN and IO

Both wrong, Is there any perfect solution. I am using Innodb engine for tables.

Comment: I don't see the queries using the `Location` table, so how do you expect to find Bangalore? About the last query, it shows what you ask for. I guess you didn't actually want to use `LEFT` join.

Comment: @ypercube: I taking that location_name from the that location table and giving input to that query. If possible any join solusion. I like hear that too !. But I don't see any matching column

Comment: Does the location table have only one column: location_name? And how are you giving the location_name as input to the query? Is it through the LIKE clause?

Comment: location table has some other fields but those are not relevant. input is from another query. That is from the location_name column