# get matched result with used keyword in mysql like query

Tags: mysql, search

I am doing `LIKE` search using `OR` condition with multiple keywords. I am wondering is that possible to get the search result and used keywords for that result.

```
SELECT * FROM `LOCATIONS` WHERE `location_name` LIKE '%United Kingdom%' OR `location_name` LIKE '%France%';
```

The query get's the matched results with both keywords, I want to get the match is from which keyword like this!

```
location_name                 usedKeyword

United Kingdom UK             United Kingdom

Lille, France                 France

London, United Kingdom        United Kingdom
```

Event it's possible I know there is one more problem if location_name matched for both keywords. I really don't have idea. How to do this.

for example, "United Kingdom and France" is location name

Why you want to do this ?

You may have this question, I experimenting all the possible ways to get the locations country name. I have countrylist table with code and names. Using that I like to get the location names

Few other experiments

1. [reverse phrase search in zend lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17655676/430112)
2. [Location search query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17624565/430112)

PS: I know, I can run the query separatly for each country. I doing the same for cities means thousands, To minimize the number of queries, I am looking for alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN location_name LIKE '%United Kingdom%'
            THEN 'United Kingdom'
            WHEN location_name LIKE '%France%'
            THEN 'France'
       END usedKeyword
FROM `LOCATIONS`
WHERE `location_name` LIKE '%United Kingdom%'
   OR `location_name` LIKE '%France%';
```

Also see the corrected `WHERE` clause. Your `WHERE` clause would return all rows.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, Do you think this query can handle the  "United Kingdom and France" location name

Comment: You could put `WHEN location_name LIKE '%United Kingdom%' AND location_name LIKE '%France%'` as the first case. But there's no easy way to generalize it to many choices, since the combinations will explode exponentially.

Comment: Yes I understand, Do you think,can we exclude the search result for this case.

Comment: Use `XOR` instead of `OR`. It's true if just one of the conditions is true, but not both.